# What can break the while read loop

Tags: bash, loops, shell, terraform, jq

I have following loop, script, bash 3.2 is installed:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -e

set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail

somefunc() {

    jq -c '.[]' <"${imports_json}" | while read -r i; do
      address=$(echo "$i" | jq -r '.address')
      item_id=$(echo "$i" | jq -r '.id')
      echo "Importing [${address}], Id: [${item_id}]"
      terraform -chdir="${terraform_dir}" import -state="${state}" "${address}" "${item_id}"
    done

    echo "Import loop is done ..."
}

...

# First invoke, all iterated
somefunc()

some other script code

# Second invoke, single import while expected to go over long list
somefunc()
```

It is simple loop over json array:

```json
[
  {
    "address": "some_terraform_resource.resource[\"some_name\"]",
    "id": "some_resource_id"
  },
  {
    "address": "another_terraform_resource.resorce",
    "id": "another_id"
  }
...
]
```

I run it in several places in long script

In one place it is just doing one iteration and quits the loop, with no error code and `echo "Import loop is done ..."` following the loop executed. So, as if this `terraform import` command acts as a `break`.

If I comment `terraform import` command out all array is iterated. If I change json content, is just one single import and break, no matter what resource is imported.

Just for experiment, I've tried:

- to suppress output (`> /dev/null`, `2>&1`).
- `|| true`, even though `terraform import` is returning 0 error code.
- comment out `set` commands at the beginning of the script
- run `terraform import ...` in subshell, `(terraform import ....)`

No effect in all cases

Trace with `bash -x`:

```
Importing [some_terraform_resource.resource["some_name"]], Id: [some_resource_id], state: "/Users/<some-path>/baseline.tfstate"
+ terraform -chdir=/Users/<some-path>/project-for-import import -state=/Users/<some-path>/baseline.tfstate 'some_terraform_resource.resource["some_name"]' some_resource_id
+ read -r i
+ echo 'Terraform import is done'
```

I am pulling my hair out, what can cause loop to break ? What are the ways to troubleshoot it?

Comment: What about if you drop `set -e`?

Comment: I am not terribly familiar with `terraform`, but it seems like importing the same resources with the same ids multiple times might be an problematic.

Comment: Does terraform read from standard input? If so, it may be stealing the rest of the list. See [BashFAQ #89](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089).

Comment: Did you try `terraform ... < /dev/null`?

Comment: Unrelated, but running 3 copies of `jq` seems inefficient (and potentially error-prone). Why not `jq -r '.[] | " \(.id) \(.address)"' <"${imports_json}" | while read -r id address; do …; done`

Comment: `while` with `read` will read lines.  Are you certain your input is exactly the same on all systems?  It could be that the system where it fails had wrong line termination characters (check Windows - Linux end of lines).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, terraform "stolen" STDIN, with the chunk fed from read, matching input variable input. Which I haven't noticed, while followed by a follow-up script output.

[Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) and [Renaud Pacalet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1773798/renaud-pacalet) replies nailed the issue.

Adding `< /dev/null` makes terraform terminate the script with a clearly seen unsatisfied variable prompt

I'll apply other suggestions as well to optimize the script. Thanks a lot for your valuable input!

Comment: If terraform needs to be able to prompt for user input from within the loop, you can read the JSON over a different file descriptor with e.g. `while read -r i <&3; do ... done 3< <(jq -c '.[]' <"${imports_json}")`